# How to prevent maven-assembly-plugin from copying natives-* classifiers from dependencySet in crazy way

Tags: java, maven, lwjgl, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project with following structure:

```
.
├── bundleA
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
├── bundleB
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
├── distribution
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── assemble
│           └── example.xml
└── pom.xml
```

`bundleA` and `bundleB` poms are trivial and not affecting this problem.

`distribution pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>distribution</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>distribution</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>distro-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/assemble/example.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`example.xml` assembly descriptor:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>example</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <includes>
                <include>org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>/libs</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
            <includes>
                <include>com.example:bundleA</include>
                <include>com.example:bundleB</include>
            </includes>
            <binaries>
                <outputDirectory>/bundles</outputDirectory>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
            </binaries>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

The problem here: when I am including lwjgl (or virtually any other project with native libraries packed in classified sub-projects) into dependencies of `distribution` project and reference it in assembly descriptor - I am getting this madness after distribution is built:

```
distribution/target/distribution-1.0-SNAPSHOT-example
├── bundles
│   ├── bundleA-1.0-SNAPSHOT-natives-linux.jar
│   ├── bundleA-1.0-SNAPSHOT-natives-osx.jar
│   ├── bundleA-1.0-SNAPSHOT-natives-windows.jar
│   ├── bundleA-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│   ├── bundleB-1.0-SNAPSHOT-natives-linux.jar
│   ├── bundleB-1.0-SNAPSHOT-natives-osx.jar
│   ├── bundleB-1.0-SNAPSHOT-natives-windows.jar
│   └── bundleB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
└── libs
    └── lwjgl-2.9.0.jar
```

In other words, every natives-*-classified subproject of lwjgl is magically copied with unique name (but exactly the same size and content of jars) by the number of bundles I have in project, which is insane.

What I want to is either a way to specify lwjgl platform-independent jars (with no natives included) or some other way to exclude this natives-* jars from resulting distribution.

Here this project on the github: https://github.com/iamtakingiteasy/maven-assembly-plugin-insanity

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might be not the best or direct solution, but using

```
<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        ...
        <binaries>
            ...
            <includeDependencies>false</includeDependencies>
            ...
        </binaries>
        ...
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

Seemd to help. The key was to start looking at bundles options, instead of trying to do something about lwjgl itself.

Also, direct exclusion of *-platform dependencies (again, in bundles section) could be the solution:

```
<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        ...
        <binaries>
            ...
            <excludes>
                <exclude>org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform</exclude>
                <exclude>net.java.jinput:jinput-platform</exclude>
            </excludes>
            ...
        </binaries>
        ...
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```